# Are there any algorithm to make real photo more fake-like?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, rendering

I know some ray-tracing algorithm can achieve very realistic photo

But,now I want to do make a fake-like photo out of a real photo

how can I do this?

Could you give me some keywords,please?

Thanks!

real photo
[image: real photo]
3d rendering photo (fake-like photo)
[image: 3d rendering]

Comment: I think the main difference is that the object on the fake photo has no shadow. A minor difference is the lag of a texture in the fake image-

Answer (score 1):

Try a bilateral filter. It will smooth the surfaces while retaining the edges.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A huge thing in fake images is the light reflection (very hard to get realistic).  Reflections or shadows that are too sharp or exact generally give away a fake image, so removing all the natural lighting, and then regenerating the lighting could give the effect your after.

To be able to do this well though, you will likely need to estimate surface normals which may be difficult if you are not in a controlled environment or know the object you are looking at quite well...